# How to draw mesh Schwartz Primitive Topology

Tags: mesh

Can you help me how can draw these geometries with add mesh **Math Function** (**XYZ Math Surface**) for this equation : (cos(x) + cos(y) + cos(z) = t)
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I can't help with mesh creation but you may like to use volume shader for visualisation.

Notice that the cube has a size of 10 units, and a scale of 1.
Cycles will give more precise results but you can use EEVEE too.
In cycles (orthographic view):
[image: schwartz volume shader]
In EEVEE  (perspective view):
[image: schwartz eevee]

I used an emission shader but you can use simple volume shader with some external light.

Comment: For the node technique, it's good to generate complex shapes but for me I want to export the mesh to the STL file, is there a way to do this with the nodes?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can [try this](https://blenderartists.org/t/converting-voxel-data-into-mesh-data/590819) or another

Comment: @saded There is an addon you can try : [Sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok)

Comment: sverchok is a good addition for nodes but is it possible to export the generated node to the mesh?

Comment: AFAIK no. I've seen some sort of converters voxel-to-mesh (for houdini) but I never tried it.

Comment: I found a solution in this link:   https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zHy8T8fQsl4, but the problem in creating these different voids (circle, rhombus, ...) of each model