# Volumetric shader and re-create Schwartz Primitive Topology in Blender 3.1

Tags: volumetrics, mathematics

I'm using eevee and trying to re-create Schwartz Primitive Topology found here [Link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191500/how-to-draw-mesh-schwartz-primitive-topology#) but using Blender 3.1, however it's not working, any ideas why? My node setup is below.

**Working Node setup:**
[image: iimg1]

**My setup which isn't working:**
[image: img2]

Attached file below:

[image]

Comment: Probably could be faster to solve it with your blend ... If you can share.

Comment: @vklidu ok I've attached the blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have scaled the cube in object mode, so that coordinates less when pi/2.

Apply scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → Scale)